# How do I pass foreign key to View page? (ADO.NET)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I have 3 SQL tables for my web application.

1. **Shipment(ssuid, sCompanyName, sFName, sMName, sLName, sAddress1, sAddress2, sCity, sState, sPostalCode, sCountry)**
2. **Packages(ppuid, psuid, pTrackingNumber)**
3. **Content(cuid, cpuid, cAmount, CNotes)**

I have a View page that retrieves Shipment info based on the tracking # entered by the user.

Here is the controller that I am using to search the shipment:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SearchByTrackingNumber(string? TrackingNumber ) {
        List<Shipment> shipments = new List<Shipment>();
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectonString))
        {
            con.Open();
            String sql = "select sSUID, packages.pPUID, sFrom, sCompanyName, sFName, sMName, sLName, sAddress1, sAddress2, sCity, sState, sPostalCode, sCountry from shipments inner join packages on shipments.sSUID = packages.pSUID where pTrackingNumber like'%" + TrackingNumber + "%' order by sDateReceived";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

                
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Shipment shipment = new Shipment();
                        shipment.SSuid = new Guid(reader["SSuid"].ToString());
                        shipment.PPuid = new Guid(reader["PPuid"].ToString());
                        shipment.SCompanyName = Convert.ToString(reader["SCompanyName"]);
                        shipment.SFname = Convert.ToString(reader["SFname"]);
                        shipment.SMname = Convert.ToString(reader["SMname"]);
                        shipment.SLname = Convert.ToString(reader["SLname"]);
                        shipment.SFrom = Convert.ToString(reader["SFrom"]);
                        shipment.SAddress1 = Convert.ToString(reader["SAddress1"]);
                        shipment.SAddress2 = Convert.ToString(reader["SAddress2"]);
                        shipment.SCity = Convert.ToString(reader["SCity"]);
                        shipment.SState = Convert.ToString(reader["SState"]);                           
                        shipment.SPostalCode = Convert.ToString(reader["SPostalCode"]);
                        shipment.SCountry = Convert.ToString(reader["SCountry"]);
                        
                        shipments.Add(shipment);
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            

        }

        return View(shipments); 
    }
```

Then, for the unique result data displayed, user has an option to add a content by clicking the ActionLink, and will fill out the form then submit it. In the View page that uses the controller above, I am passing the PPuid by using

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Content", "AddContent","Content", new {id=shipment.PPuid})
```

The content view page successfully passes the accurate PPuid in url. But how do I actually display it (as **cpuid**, the foreign key in **Content** table) in **@Html.HiddenFor** so I can POST it to the database as I submit the form?

For more information, here is the controller I have written as the controller so far.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddContent([FromForm] Guid id, Content content)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectonString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("POST_Content", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CPuid", content.CPuid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAmount", content.CAmount);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNotes", content.CNotes);

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close() ;
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Shipment");
    }

}
```

**View**

```
 @model Receiving.Models.Content
    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        
    }
    
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddContent", "Content", new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CPuid) // I honestly have no idea what to do here to print the id I passed
    
    }
```

Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: What's up with the `like'%" + TrackingNumber + "%' order ` concatenation? You use parameters later on in the question, so presumably you know how bad that is.

Comment: that is for searching based on the TrackingNumber I entered in `@Html.TextBox()`.

Comment: Yes, and it's wide open to injection. You **need** to use a query parameter here, or your database will be trivial to hack. It will be simple to post anything I want to the TrackingNumber at that http endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will revise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not shown your `View` where you are initializing your `form` so I do not know the exact binding of your `Model` structure. In simplest terms, you can use the following `HtmlHelper` to store your value in a hidden field:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.cpuid, new { Value = ViewBag.shipmentPPuid })
```

Now when you submit your form, you should be able to get the value of `cpuid`.

We will go with this approach only in which you can add your current `PPuid` to a `ViewBag`. So your `GET` method will be:

```
public ActionResult AddContent(string id) 
{  
  //Assign to ViewBag
  ViewBag.shipmentPPuid=id;
  return View(); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info. I am calling `@model Receiving.Models.content` in the beginning of the form, and using that `AddContent` controller in `@Html.BeginForm()` so  `shipment.PPuid` wouldn't work.

Comment: @smbbb Updated my answer to use `ViewBag` for your case.

Comment: Than you for the edit. However, I still get an error on `PPuid` part in `SearchByTrackingNumber` controller you fixed for me. It says **List<Shipment> does not contain a definition for `PPuid` and no accessible extension method  `PPuid` etc**

Comment: @smbbb Okay so now I see it. Can you please post your View code also. I need to see what you are attempting to do.

Comment: View code for `AddContent`? If so, I attached it minutes ago at the end of the question.

Comment: @smbbb Can you show you `AddContent` get method ? I would presume that you can assign the `PPuid` in that method.

Comment: Yes sir. I normally just write a simple Get method for POST method since it's just to view the page. `public ActionResult AddContent() {  return View(); }`

Comment: @smbbb Updated the answer as required to get your value via the `GET` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253217/discussion-between-smbbb-and-rahul-sharma).